# Functionality of a horseshoe orbit around a gas giant in a binary star system

Tags: orbital-mechanics, solar-system

So I'm starting a book and this idea popped in my head. Horseshoe orbits are really cool and all, but what if you throw in another star. Of course it did have a reason, I want my main civilization that I'm focusing on to have astrology deeply ingrained in their culture and peoples.

As such I want to fill the sky with as much as possible. But I haven't been able to find anything on this. The binary stars might not even affect anything, but I wanted to make sure before going further. Again I haven't found anything saying that the formation is impossible, but I also haven't found anything saying otherwise.

Comment: A horseshoe orbit only _appears_ to be a horseshoe from the point of view of another body which shares a similar orbit with it. Both bodies are in perfectly normal elliptical orbits. If elliptical orbits around the gas giant are possible, then "horseshoe" orbits are too.

Answer (score 2):

A horseshoe orbit is a co-orbital configuration, so if a planet is in a horseshoe orbit relative to a gas giant, both the smaller planet and the gas giant are actually *orbiting* the parent star.

Basically there are two ways to get a binary-star system with stable planetary orbits: the two stars are very close (and planets orbit them as a single source of gravity) or one star has the planets and the other is comparatively very distant.

In general, multiple systems tend to be "divisible" into two-body systems.

For example, Alpha Centauri is two close stars, A and B, orbited by a vastly more distant star, Proxima, which has a planet.

- the A/B system is largely unaffected by Proxima
- Proxima orbits A+B as essentially a single gravity source
- Proxima's planet orbits Proxima largely uninfluenced by A/B

If you make the second star very distant, it wouldn't be visible as a "sun disk", but would be an incredibly bright point of light. (A Sun-like star at 1,000 AU would be 1,000,000 times dimmer than the Sun as seen from Earth - between the brightness of a full moon and a half moon, but concentrated into a single point.)

[The Sun is about 400,000 times brighter than the full Moon, as seen from Earth, and (counter-intuitively) the full Moon is much more than twice as bright as the half Moon.]

Comment: Not directly related, perhaps, but these sorts of configurations may not be stable over really long timespans (various asteroids seem to wander in and out of co-orbital configurations with Earth), so if a habitable planet is now in a co-orbital configuration with a gas giant, it may end up somewhere else 'soon', possibly outside the habitable zone...

Answer (score 1):

I am rather sure that the only way to make it work is to have the binary stellar system to not be one where the two stars are closer than the giant gas is to the main star.

If the second star orbits the first one from far away, it might have negligible influence on perturbing the orbital motion of the horseshoe orbiting body.

If the second star orbits the first one closely, I have the impression that the gravitational perturbation won't let the horseshoe orbit exist for very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Horseshoe orbits are normal elliptical orbits, with the "horseshoe" only occurring from the perspective of the two objects. Binary star systems can often be treated like normal solitary stars, by using their common center of mass (barycenter) in the same way you would use a single stars' center of mass.
The only exception would be if the planets were orbiting one star rather than both (i.e. an "S-type" orbit); since you want a habitable planet, this would probably only happen if one star was much larger than the other, or the two were (relatively) distant. Even in this case, the planets could have stable elliptical orbits and thus be in a horseshoe orbit with regards to one another.

Answer (score 0):

The horseshoe movement is purely subjective to the companion planet, but yes it would make for GREAT mythology. The time between meetings is great, many years to a few centuries. It is regular, and predictable, and has a cyclic nature longer than human lifespan, possibly longer than accurate oral traditions.

*"My son, in the time of ENkwa, when my grandfather's grandfather walked the plains, the Blue Star did show in the evening. And it blessed the rains, and the Tribe flourished. But then did the evil T'Ka'Wa insult ENkwa, and he withdrew from us, fading away in the twilight.

Yet LO! The Blue Star approaches again, but now it appears in the morning. Does ENkwa return to bless us again, or does He bring death, and destruction, and the wailing of maidens, and bad breath, and the sour corncob, for He approaches not from his usual place, but from {gasp} The Other Side?"*

Ok, great setting. Now, can we make this work in a Binary solar system?

As others have mentioned, there are three scenarios.

1. The second star is way far out of the solar system. The orbital period of the planets are many,many times quicker than the orbital period of the binary star system.
   In this case, the second star is a very slowly migrating beacon in the sky, and has no short or long term deleterious effect on the planetary orbits, including the somewhat delicate Horseshoe orbits.
2. The second star is a very close binary, and the planets orbit around the common barycentre of the two central stars.
   In this case, you have reasonably normal day/night cycles, with two suns visually close to each other. Colorful double shadows may prevail.
   The two stars orbit each other with a period *much* shorter than planetary orbital times, thus again they have negligible effect on the planets, even such delicate things as horseshoe orbits.
3. The stars orbit each other with a period somewhat similar to planetary orbits.
   This will disrupt delicate orbits like the horseshoe orbits.
   It will also disrupt robust orbits, like the moon circling Earth.
   Actually, is is better named not as "Solar System", but "interstellar Bowling Alley" as the orbits of *all* the planets with orbital periods of the same magnitude as the stars' orbits around each other, will eventually in the *short term* of astronomical time be flung out of the system as a whole. 3-body gravitational systems are not stable if the mass of 2 or more of the bodies are comparable. Only when you have a *tiny* orbiting a medium, which is orbiting a **huge** is the setup reasonably stable.

So really:
If your system is stable enough for a *normal* planetary orbit to exist, and is not a special case with the planet stuck in a Lagrange point or in resonance with the stars, then it is stable enough for an additional horseshoe orbit intersecting that planet's path.